# Read XML files tag if (resOb.readyState==4)

Tags: javascript, xml

there is an XML file an I cant read the tags, this is the xml file data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<a>Hello</a>
<b>World</b>
<c>
    <d id="1">How are you</d>
    <d id="2">Where are you</d>
</c>
```

The JS code:

```
  function handleResponse(){
    if(resOb.readyState==4){
        var xmlDoc = resOb.responseXML;
        alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]);
    }
  }
```

There is no alert. I cant read the first tag a (Hello). I can try `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")` or whatever but its not working. If i say `var xmlDoc = resOb.responseText;` then i get the whole XML as String. But i just want to read some tags and attributes.

I would like to read the tag d with the attribute 2 but im not even able to read a. Whats wrong with the code?

Comment: That's invalid XML; you need to have a single root element.

Comment: Even if i have one root <a> its not working

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to ensure:

- Your XML is invalid, it needs a root node
- The response ContentType header sent by the server should be "text/xml"
- Retrieve the document directly via resOb.responseXML as in your code snippet

Then it should work as you expected.

Comment: The response ContentType header sent by the server should be "text/xml" - how can i check this or how to set this?

Comment: This needs to be done on the web server that sends the response. Are you in control of it? What language is it using, what kind of server?

Comment: That makes it interesting :) What does resOb.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"); say?